# NancyFx forward request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nancy

I developed a REST application using the awesome NancyFx framework.
What I need to do now is redirect all incoming http request methods (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) to another Host throught the Nancy application itself.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Did you ever succeed in this?